# FileDownload Not working ASP MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to download a file from server but this thing won't work. Been tring doing it for more than 2 weeks. Here is the code:

IN CSHTML PAGE:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="docView">
  <a href="#" onclick="docView('{{:id}}')">View</a>
</script>
<script>
function docView(id) {
        docId = id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Profile")' + "?docid=" + docId,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

            },            
    });
</script>
```

IN MVC Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(Guid? docid)
    {
        int i = 1;
        string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhysicalDocumentPath"];
        JApplicantDocument value = new JApplicantDocument();
        var response = new Response();
        var fName = "";
        var savefileName = "";
        var fileSavePath = "";
        var prevPath = "";
        var nextPath = "";           

        try
        {
            IApplicantDataService applicantDataService = new ApplicantDataService();
            response = applicantDataService.GetDocument(docid, value);
            var fileName = value.ApplicantId + "_" + value.DocumentName;
            fName = fileName;
            savefileName = fileName;
            fileSavePath = Path.Combine(key, fileName);
            prevPath = fileSavePath;
            nextPath = fileSavePath;
            var tmp = fileName.Split('.');
            var tmp1 = tmp[0];
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(nextPath)) //to get the latest file
            {
                tmp = fileName.Split('.');
                fileName = tmp1 + i.ToString();
                fileName = fileName + "." + tmp[1];
                savefileName = fileName;
                nextPath = Path.Combine(key, savefileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(nextPath))
                {
                    prevPath = nextPath;

                }
                i++;
                tmp = prevPath.Split(new string[] { "Docs\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                fName = tmp[1];
                response.Message = prevPath;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Utils.Write(e);
        }

        return File(prevPath, value.Format);                       

    }
```

I just want on click of View button to download the file as per this(http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/file-download-sample-in-mvc-day-40/). i cannot use location.href(...) directly in  tag due to the fact that i'm using it in script jsrender which is being used in syncfusion grid controls. Hence I wont be able to get the docid at all.

Comment: You cannot download a file using ajax. You need to make a redirect - e.g. `location.href="yourUrl";`

Comment: can you please suggest how to do that. all the code is above itself. i cannot directly call location.href in script cz of syncfusion gridcontrolls compatibility issue

Comment: There is no mention of 'syncfusion gridcontrols' in your question!

Comment: Yes sorry about that. but that is the thing. sorry i'll update it now. But i'm not downloading anything from ajax . I am just making a call so that view is called and file gets downloaded right ?

Comment: Wkat do you mean cant use it _directly in tag_ (what 'tag')? You just need `function docView(id) { location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Profile")' + "?docid=" + docId; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your code worked. But it's directly opening the file  in the same tab. Can I make it open in a new tab or can I make it download ?

Comment: you can use window.open instead of location.href. Lots of examples online if you google that

Comment: windows.open will need url. then it will be document path which I do not want. This method is also not downloading but just opening the file directly .(even I dont know how). it should download not view file.

Comment: "windows.open will need url" ... so does location.href. There's no difference between them in that respect. You can do `window.open('@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Profile")' + "?docid=" + docId);`

Comment: As for forcing a download rather than opening the file within the browser - of course depending on the file type it may download anyway, because the browser doesn't know how to display it, and different browsers have a different range of files they can display, depending what extensions/plugins are installed (e.g. Adobe for PDFs), but if you want to try and force all file types to be downloaded directly to the disk, then search on google for "asp.net mvc force file download instead of open", there are lots of suggestions and examples.

Comment: actually if I'm running from localhost then if I click on View , the browser asks for either download or open the document but the same code on server directly opens the file and not asks the user anything.

Comment: could be to do with MIME type mappings on the server, or what headers get sent by default. Like I said, if you google it there are ways to ensure it's always a download (by setting certain headers in the response)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704078/how-to-download-a-file-through-ajax-request-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @MohanSrinivas the "accepted" answer to the question in your link is a load of nonsense - see the comment I wrote under it some time ago. It suggests calling the URL via ajax (which won't cause the file to be downloaded, because downloading files via ajax isn't possible), and then calling the same URL again in the "success" callback of the meaningless ajax call. Makes no sense at all (just like the answer to this question which you posted and then deleted), and I'm not sure why you would suggest it?