# MVC FilePathResult not downloading file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

FilePathResult is not downloading file

I have tried returning File(...), tried changing the file to be a blank workbook, changed the location of the file

```
public ActionResult GenerateSupplyInformation(List<string> serialNumbers)
        {            
                if (serialNumbers != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.strmsg = "";
                    foreach (var serialNumber in serialNumbers)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialNumber))
                        {
                            var results = _ftRepository.GetSupplyInformation(serialNumber);

                            var filePath = _documentGenerator.GenerateSupplyInformation(serialNumber, results);

                            return new FilePathResult(filePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return null;
        }
```

I would expect the file to download when this method is hit as no exceptions are thrown

---

Here is an updated version of the problem

Here is the ajax call with the downloadfile call removed

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                //url: "/JQueryAjaxCall/AjaxPostCall",
                url: "/RWM/GenerateSupplyInformation",
                data: JSON.stringify(models),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert("response");
                }
            }
        );
```

Here is the new(er) probably slightly different, although it behaves the same, controller method

```
public ActionResult GenerateSupplyInformation(List<LxStockDataModel> records)
    {
        try
        {
            if (records != null)
            {
                ViewBag.strmsg = "";
                foreach (var serialNumber in records)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialNumber.Serial_No))
                    {
                        var results = _ftRepository.GetSupplyInformation(serialNumber.Serial_No);

                        var filePath = _documentGenerator.GenerateSupplyInformation(serialNumber.Serial_No, results);

                        var file =  new FilePathResult(filePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                        //return file;
                        return File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                    }
                }
                return View("RWMSummary", records);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Exception(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

With either returns in the method, File or FilePathResult, I get the same behaviour that the file will not download.  I have to be doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

use FileResult insted of action result

```
public FileResult GenerateSupplyInformation(List<string> serialNumbers)
    {            
            if (serialNumbers != null)
            {
                ViewBag.strmsg = "";
                foreach (var serialNumber in serialNumbers)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialNumber))
                    {
                        var results = _ftRepository.GetSupplyInformation(serialNumber);

                        var filePath = _documentGenerator.GenerateSupplyInformation(serialNumber, results);

                        return new FilePathResult(filePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be any different.  The file is created as I can see it in the directory I have specified.  However, the file should download int he browser, but does not

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the "File" method ? Like this :

```
public ActionResult GenerateSupplyInformation(List<string> serialNumbers)
    {            
            if (serialNumbers != null)
            {
                ViewBag.strmsg = "";
                foreach (var serialNumber in serialNumbers)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serialNumber))
                    {
                        var results = _ftRepository.GetSupplyInformation(serialNumber);

                        var filePath = _documentGenerator.GenerateSupplyInformation(serialNumber, results);

                        return File(filePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "YourDownloadedFileName.xls");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

It expects "filePath" to be the full path of the file (with name and extension)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Even if filePath was just a string to a workbook on a different directory it does the same thing of not downloading


                            `var filePath = @"c:\\ws\\Book1.xlsx";
                            return File(filePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", Path.GetFileName(filePath));`

Comment: Would it be possible that your application just can't access that path/file ?

Could you try to download a file in the application folder (like an image in "Content") ?

Comment: I have a feeling that it might be the ajax call on the button to hit this controller method that cannot handle responses.

$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/RWM/GenerateSupplyInformation",
                    data: JSON.stringify(models),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
window.location.href = '/RWM/DownloadFile?file=' + response;
                    }
                }
            );

Comment: Yeah, it's the AJAX part.

If I'm not wrong, you're trying to redirect to your "/RWM/DownloadFile" url with your stream file return by GenerateSupplyInformation which won't work.

You might find it better explained there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30704519/6488079

Comment: Ok , its been a while since i looked at this, my apologies.  I have removed the response action in the ajax call to Download file, however, it still doesn't download the generated file.