# Is there any way to redirect to another action after file downloading in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple method to download a XML file which works OK for me:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string fileName)
{
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        return Content("fileName not present");
    }

    var filePath = Path.Combine(this.pathToInvalidFolder, fileName);

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
         await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
            
    return File(memory, "text/xml", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
}
```

After file is downloaded, I want to redirect user to another page, where user is notified that the file has been downloaded successfully, something like.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string fileName)
{
     if (fileName == null)
     {
          return Content("fileName not present");
     }
    
     var filePath = Path.Combine(this.pathToInvalidFolder, fileName);
    
     var memory = new MemoryStream();
     using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
     {
          await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
     }
     memory.Position = 0;
                
     return File(memory, "text/xml", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

     //AFTER FILE IS DOWNLOADED, I WANT TO DO...
     return RedirectToAction("ShowDownloadResult")

}
```

Is there any way to achieve that? Maybe I need to use some JavaScript to trigger a redirect event after hitting the "Download" button? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2533-tracking-file-download-events-using-javascript-and-coldfusion.htm

Comment: @el_nektarin what you can do is convert the memory stream to base64 array then you can return a object which consist of base64 array and the url you want to redirect to. Once you have both in client side you can save that base64 array as file and redirect to the page where you want to.

Comment: You can download the file using AJAX and redirect the page on AJAX call success.

Comment: @RajeshG I tried AJAX, but it doesn't download file now; in my C# debug it just came to the `return File()` statement, executed it and nothing more happened (file hasn't been downloaded as I said). In JS debug everything was OK, the success call has been executed as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704078/how-to-download-a-file-through-ajax-request-in-asp-net-mvc-4) helps.

Comment: @RajeshG thanks bro, I already fixed that, I'll add the resulting code.

Answer (score 0):

As @RajeshG mentioned, it could be done by AJAX (with jQuery in my case). The JS code is:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".download-button", function () {
            const fileName = $(this).attr("id");
            downloadUserFile(fileName);
        });

    function downloadUserFile(fileName) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/Download",
            type: "GET",
            data: { fileName: fileName },
            success: function(data) {
                fetch(data)
                    .then(resp => resp.blob())
                    .then(blob => {
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        const a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.style.display = "none";
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = fileName;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                        alert("Your file has downloaded!");
                        //style it as you want, if you need some redirect, call another AJAX
                    })
                    .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(`An error ${error} occured`);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If the customer clicks the download link, then navigates away before the download completes, what happens?

Comment: @NathanMiller frankly, I don't know this one. My task is to do this one on some small files, and I don't have big ones to check that